# How to get folder path using partial folder name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder that I'm not sure of its full name - I have only part of the folder name. So I am trying to find a vba code that will be given a partial folder path, and will return the full path.

For example: The full path is: "C:\Documents\Folder1ABC", but I only know that the path is something like this: "C:\Documents\Folder1*".

Is there a VBA code that can solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Dir` function...

```
Sub testDir()
    Debug.Print Dir("c:\documents\Folder1*", vbDirectory)
End Sub
```

We use the `vbDirectory` attribute to specify that only a directory will be returned. More details at [MSDN Dir function page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Great, it wroks! Thanks a lot! :)